# How to converter Pyw to executable in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-2.7, wxpython, executable

i have a wxPython(with Python 2.7 64x) script, and this script was been created on Ubuntu 12.
Well, i wanna execute this wxPython as executable on Windows(doubleclick), but on Ubuntu.

I tried change property on wxPython(right click in permissions[check box] and Chmod: x) and prepend "#!/usr/bin/python" on file, but not work.

Right now, i can just run wxPython from terminal.

Any idea how to do what I need?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To create executables on windows and linux you could use [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)

you will have to be on windows to create windows executable.